# Can I pasteurize milk in a jam jar?

Tags: yogurt, steaming, jam, glass, containers

The [InstantPot manual](http://instantpot.com/wp-content/uploads/IP-DUO/InstantPot-IP-DUO-Manual-English.pdf) says that I can use a bottle or container to make yogurt. It says to first pasteurize the milk (using the steam function to heat it to at least 180F/83C) then cool to 115F/46C and add starter. Can I use a jam jar for this?

I'm a bit afraid of breaking the glass - but on the other hand the jam jar should be prepared to handle some heat difference (namely between heated jam and room).

Comment: pasteurizing kills microbes such as bacteria in raw milk, Depending on where you live, you may not even be able to buy raw milk,. Making yogurt involves encouraging good bacteria to grow. So this is the very opposite of pasteurizing. What are you trying to do, specifically, and what temperatures are involved?

Comment: @KateGregory Kill the bad bacteria before I introduce the ones I want. The receipy calls for boiling to >72 C and then cooling to 45 C before introducing culture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any jar sold for home canning will work for what you want. They are designed to handle temperatures higher than 212°F/100°C.

What you want to avoid is thermal shock - a large and rapid change of temperature. Don't put cool/cold jar(s) in boiling water, don't put hot jar(s) directly on cool counter or in refrigerator/freezer. Don't fill cold jar(s) with hot contents and vice-versa.